# Solving a triangle given two side lengths and the measure of a non-included angle

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles

Let's say given an angle A = 46 °, side a = 2.29 and b = 2.71

I figured that the angle B = 58.4 by saying:

$$B = \sin^{-1} \left(\frac{ 2.71  \sin{46^{\circ}}}{2.29}\right)=58.4^{\circ}$$

But I think that angle C is incorrect:

$$C = \sin^{-1} \left(\frac{2.29 \sin{58.4^{\circ}}}{2.71}\right)=46.03^{\circ}$$

Someone who can help me? what do I do wrong and how should it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find sine of angle $B$ using sine rule: $sin\beta=(2.71\cdot sin46)/2.29=0.85 \Rightarrow \beta=58.35$. You got this correctly. Now, using the fact that sum of angles in triangle is 180 degrees, you get angle $C=180-46-58.35=75.65$ (all angles are in degrees).

Once you have two angles, there's no need to re-use sine rule. Calculation is more complicated and you can make a mistake more easily.

If you want to calculate sides of triangle, use cosine rule.

Comment: There's a second solution that you didn't account for.

Answer (score 5):

While the other answers have covered the basic use of the Law of Sines, they've all missed a critical point: there are **two** triangles that fit your given information.  Here is the triangle you've found:

[image: basic LoS solution triangle]

But, when you're solve $\sin B=\frac{b\sin A}{a}$, there are *two* solutions that could be angles in a triangle, $B_1=\arcsin\left(\frac{b\sin A}{a}\right)$ (the one you found) and $B_2=180°-\arcsin\left(\frac{b\sin A}{a}\right)$.  Using this second possible measure for $B$ won't always yield a triangle, but in this case it does:

[image: LoS solution triangle from the supplement]

Here are both triangles pictured together:

[image: the two LoS solution triangles]

This issue with the Law of Sines, sometimes called the "ambiguous case," is almost certainly what [the picture in your question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/106047/72) is about.

See also [my answer here on general techniques for triangle-solving](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/106540/72).

Comment: Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

According to Sine Law :

$$\frac{b}{\sin \beta} =\frac{a}{\sin \alpha} \Rightarrow  \beta = \arcsin \left(\frac{b\cdot \sin \alpha}{a}\right)$$

Once you find angle $\beta$ you can calculate $\gamma$ from :

$$\gamma = 180° - (\alpha + \beta)$$

Comment: There's a second solution that you didn't account for.

Answer (score 1):

Your application of the sine rule to get $C$ is incorrect. It should be

$$\frac{\sin C}{\sin A} = \frac{c}{a}$$

but you wrote

$$\frac{\sin C}{\sin A} \overset{?}{=} \frac{a}{b}$$

The correct angle can be worked out from the sum of angles, as pointed out in the other answers.

Comment: There's a second solution that you didn't account for.